# Show taxonomies wordpress within a script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I don't have much experience with javascript, I need some help, I have implemented an autocomplete input:

```
<input type="text" name="searchField"  id="form-autocomplete" class="form-control mdb-autocomplete">
```

and these are the values ​​it returns:

```
<script>
    var states = [
        "Alabama",
        "Alaska",
        "Arizona",
        "Arkansas",
        "California",
        "Colorado",
        "Connecticut",
        "Delaware",
        "Florida",
        "Georgia",
        "Hawaii",
        "Idaho",
        "Illnois",
        "Indiana",
        "Iowa",
        "Kansas",
        "Kentucky",
        "Louisiana",
        "Maine",
        "Maryland",
        "Massachusetts",
        "Michigan",
        "Minnesota",
        "Mississippi",
        "Missouri",
        "Montana",
        "Nebraska",
        "Nevada",
        "New Hampshire",
        "New Jersey",
        "New Mexico",
        "New York",
        "North Carolina",
        "North Dakota",
        "Ohio",
        "Oklahoma",
        "Oregon",
        "Pennsylvania",
        "Rhode Island",
        "South Carolina",
        "South Dakota",
        "Tennessee",
        "Texas",
        "Utah",
        "Vermont",
        "Virginia",
        "Washington",
        "West Virginia",
        "Wisconsin",
        "Wyoming"
    ];

    $('#form-autocomplete').mdbAutocomplete({
        data: states
    });
</script>
```

now my goal is to replace these script values ​​with the list of my taxonomies which i get via php:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms('categoria', $args );
foreach( $terms as $term ){
    echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>&nbsp;';
}
?>
```

the question is how can I insert my taxonomies as script values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
var states = <?php
    echo json_encode(
        array_map(
            function($term){ return $term->name; },
            get_terms('categoria', $args )
        )
    );
?>;
states.length||(states=[]);
$('#form-autocomplete').mdbAutocomplete({
    data: states
});
</script>
```

If this looks confusing, this is the code that does the same:

```
<script>
var states = <?php
    $terms = get_terms('categoria', $args );
    $term_names = [];
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        $term_names[] = $term->name;
    }
    echo json_encode( $term_names );
?>;
states.length||(states=[]);
$('#form-autocomplete').mdbAutocomplete({
    data: states
});
</script>
```

Explanation: The whole `<?php ... ?>` block prints a JSON which is a valid javascript object that can be assigned, so `<?php ... ?>` in html will become `["Alabama","Alaska", ...]`

P.S. due to the php behavior, printing an empty array as JSON would cause to output `{}` instead of `[]`

Comment: note - This only works in a PHP file - Not in a JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with this library

Change HTML like this

```
<input type="text" name="searchField"  id="form-autocomplete" class="form-control">
```

Change JS like this

```
$( "#form-autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
     source: states
});
```

Add below scripts and CSS files

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.2.1/proj4.js
https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css
https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
```

Thanks.